# Borderline Personality Disorder vs Borderline Personality Organization

Tags: personality-disorder, psychoanalysis, diagnosis, dsm

Most of psychoanalytic sources, including [DSM](https://1.cdn.edl.io/XRT6WhAdm7L7xioV6lr2dVK1GoWWCeq614ySeGavmjPY2rV5.pdf), talks about Borderline Personality disorder and only disorder. Meanwhile [Nancy McWilliams](https://therapistuncensored.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Psychoanalytic_Diagnosis_-_Nancy_McWilli.pdf) talks about Borderline Personality Organization. Also she mentions:

> Kernberg (1984), one of the originators of the concept, began having to differentiate between “borderline personality organization” (BPO) and the DSM’s “borderline personality disorder” (BPD).

Meanwhile people with Borderline Personality Organization is described by McWilliams as quite abnormal and problematic. So it stays unclear **what exactly the difference between Borderline Personality Disorder and Borderline Personality Organization?**

**Also, are there any difference between Psychotic Personality Disorder vs Psychotic Personality Organization?** McWilliams doesn't seem to say anything on that topic.

Comment: have you tried reading Kernberg on that?

Comment: @Ooker I don't have the book. Is it free online?  Also it says "***began*** to differentiate" and it was 36 years ago, I suppose the criteria has changed greatly to this day.

Comment: I don't know. By the way, the author says: "I am probably fighting a losing battle in trying to preserve the original meaning of the term “borderline”". I agree that we should start calling BPD by a better name. It will be awkward at the start, but then everyone will get use to it.